# Does a Nicaraguan citizen need a visa for the UK?

Tags: uk, international-travel, visas-on-arrival, nicaraguan-citizens

I don't need a visa to enter certain European countries as a tourist... but I am not sure about the UK. A friend invited me to go to the UK. I will stay in Amsterdam for a month before going there.  Any idea if I need a visa to enter the UK if I am already in a European country?

Comment: What passport do you hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to apply for a visa in advance to enter the UK with a Nicaraguan passport, as long as your period of stay is less than six months, [according to Timaticweb](http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=NI&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GB&user=DL&subuser=DELTAB2C). However, the length of the visa issued on arrival is at the discretion of the immigration official who processes you at border control.

Comment: The [UKBA Page](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/general/visa/) confirms that Nicaragua is not one of the countries whos nationals need a visa